# Ganglia + Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, ganglia

I want to monitor the cassandra metrics on Ganglia monitor since Ganglia is already installed in the cluster. I went through the list of gmond python module. I couldn't find any for cassandra. Can somebody help me here

Thanks 
V Sairam

Answer (score 1):

You can use the metrics reporter to send metrics into ganglia from Cassandra. The blog post http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/pluggable-metrics-reporting-in-cassandra-2-0-2 describes process that would work for it as well.

Add the [metrics-ganglia jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-ganglia/2.1.5/metrics-ganglia-2.1.5.jar) to your class path (drop in servers lib folder), add to the last line of your `cassandra-env.sh`:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.metricsReporterConfigFile=/etc/cassandra/gangliaReporting.yaml"
```

Then create a `/etc/cassandra/gangliaReporting.yaml` like (note: this particular config is untested):

```
ganglia:
  -
    period: 60
    timeunit: 'SECONDS'
    hosts:
      - host: 'gmond.domain.local'
        port: 8649
      - host: 'gmond-backup.domain.local'
        port: 8649
    gmondConf: '/etc/ganglia/gmond.conf'
    predicate:
      useQualifiedName: true
      patterns:
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Cache.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ClientRequest.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Storage.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ThreadPools.+"
```

check out https://github.com/addthis/metrics-reporter-config for details on the reporter config yaml.

Comment: I am getting the following error : Trying to load metrics-reporter-config from file: metrics.yaml
ERROR  Tried to enable GangliaReporter, but class com.yammer.metrics.reporting.GangliaReporter was not found
 WARN  No reporters were succesfully enabled

Comment: I updated link to metrics-ganglia, it was linked to the dropwizard GangliaReporter, not the yammer one.

Comment: I want to use metrics-ganglia itself. how to link it to that.

Comment: its a component in https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics. it has to match up with version of metrics used in C* which has changed over time.